# Saving very large matrices in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I got this problem in Matlab for saving a very large matrix A.

For saving I use

```
save(sprintf('databs%d.mat'), 'A')

Warning: Variable `'A'` cannot be saved to a MAT-file whose version is
older than 7.3.
To save this variable, use the -v7.3 switch.
```

Which command should I type to save `A`?

Comment: Did you followed the advice and set the `-v7.3` switch?

Comment: I don't know how, this is the question

Comment: Read the documentation for `save`!

Comment: save('myfile.mat','-v7.3'). As Daniel suggest, I would recommend you to read the documentation for save. Alternatively, this article could be of interest http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/mat-file-versions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
save('-v7.3', 'yourFileName', 'A')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another alternative available now.

To save the large matrices (for example My_var, having size Nvar1 x Nvar2), without slowing the other processes...

```
myObject = matfile('myFilename.mat','Writable',true);
myObject.myVariablenameinObject(1:Nvar1,1:Nvar2)=My_var(1:Nvar1,1:Nvar2)
```

By setting 'Writable' as true, you can access, modify or write data. If you don't want to write. Just use:

```
myObject = matfile('myFilename.mat')
```

For more details, refer to [this link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/load-parts-of-variables-from-mat-files.html).